# I can't access my stack overflow account using the laptop

Tags: javascript

I have  a red line saying 
Stack overflow requires external Javascript from another domain,  which is blocked or failed to load.
I tried everything and i really have a question but i can't copy the code on the phone can anyone help me please what shall i do to get it to work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on meta.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Firefox + Decentraleyes, it is work for me.!